# Run time error '91' when using MSSql

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I'm making a program in which I have to check some column values in another table before trying to save values in a different table.. both tables are in SQL.

I tried my best to do it myself but I get the error near the highlighted line.

`rs.open(insert into testreport_tb1...`

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim BrdSrNo As String
Dim Result As Boolean
Dim machineName As String

machineName = Environ("computername")
' Ready objects for use.
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
BrdSrNo = BoardSrNo.Text
Result = False
' Connect.
cn.Open "{Here I give the connection string}"
' Fetch a recordset.
rs.Open "select * from testreport_tb1 where board_SrNo = '" & BrdSrNo & "' order by test_DateTime desc", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
' Display value, and total recordcount.
MsgBox rs.Fields(3)
MsgBox rs.Fields(8)
'MsgBox rs.RecordCount
stage_Status = rs.Fields(3)
stage_Id = rs.Fields(8)
rs.Close
cn.Close

If stage_Status = "C" Then
If stage_Id = "True" Then
rs.Open "insert into testreport_tb1 values('" & BrdSrNo & "',3,GETDATE(),'" & Result & "',NULL,'" & machineName & "',' KO ','A','D')", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
MsgBox "saved"
End If
End If
' Close and release objects.
rs.Close
cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: why is there `<!-- language: lang-js -->***` in the failing line?

Comment: I tried to highlight the error line while posting.. thats it.. @Sebas

Comment: That's a while I haven't done any vb... but it's weird to me that you're using a recordset for an insert statement. I think you need to use `cn.Execute sql, , adCmdText`, with `sql` being your query.

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked. You should research the ADO CreateParameter method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember, you can't use `rs.Open` when executing [DML statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848766.aspx), (insert, update or delete), but only when you are executing select statements.

Also, you need to use [`ADODB.Command`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677502(v=vs.85).aspx) and set parameters instead of concatenating strings to create your insert statement, otherwise it's an open door for [sql injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) attacks.

It's been a very long time since the last time I've worked with ADODB, but your insert code should look something like this:

```
If stage_Status = "C" And  stage_Id = "True" Then
     Dim cmd as new ADODB.Command
     cmd.CommandText = "insert into testreport_tb1 values(?, 3, GETDATE(), ?, NULL, ?, ' KO ', 'A', 'D')"

     cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

     Set param = cmd.CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput)
     param.Value = BrdSrNo
     cmd.Parameters.Append param

     Set param = cmd.CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput)
     param.Value = Result
     cmd.Parameters.Append param

     Set param = cmd.CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput)
     param.Value = machineName
     cmd.Parameters.Append param

     cmd.Execute

  MsgBox "saved"
End If
```

**Note:** Code was written directly here, and as I wrote, it's been a long time since I've used ADODB, so there might be mistakes in the code. However, this is the proper way of executing an insert statement with ADODB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. @Zohar Peled But when run the program it seems like it is not entering into the If loop.. Its not being executed.. what shall I do..

Comment: If it doesn't go inside the if then it shouldn't have done that in your code either. All I've done in the if is combine the 2 statements into 1... debug your code and see what values you have in stage_status and in stage_id.